# How to access camera in UI thread and background service simultaneously

Tags: android, android-camera

I am developing an android based application which is displaying the camera preview in the UI thread and simultaneously it should be able to capture images. But I am not able to access camera using two processes at once. How can I do this?

Comment: Show us your code. Also why are you running your service in another process?

Comment: While the foreground process displays the map background process should send captured images,position and accelerometer readings to the server. But camera preview should be displayed on the ui thread

Comment: You describe the standard way camera apps all work. Why do you need two processes? The modern camera2 API support capture of high resolution photos without suspending live preview. Check the official [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic).